# Stop Words not being removed from list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, stop-words

I am doing some analysis on a large corpus, but my function to remove custom stop words is just not working. I tried several different solutions from questions already asked here, but I can't find why words are not being removed from the Test list.

Any help pointing out my stupidness is welcome.

```
test = [['acesso em',
  'agindo',
  'alegre',
  'ambiente escolar',
  'ambientes digitais',
  'anual',
  'aplicativos digitais',
  'apresentar conclusões',
  'argumentação cuidado',
  'articuladas projeto',
  'associadas eixos',
  'associação',
  'ativas',
  'atos linguagem',
  'avaliar oportunidades',
  'bairro',
  'base critérios',
  'base estudos',
  'bibliográfica exploratória',
  'blogs',
  'buscando apresentar',
  'campo artístico']]
removed = ['anual']
new_words = [word for word in test if word not in removed]
new_words
```

Comment: This works and removes the word 'annul' from the list

Comment: Any ideas why it might not be working for me? haha

Comment: Works for me too. What exactly is not working?

Comment: The word just stays in the list. I am running this on a Jupiter Notebook, don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: `test` is a nested list, i.e., `test` is a list with one member - another list.  Is that intended?  If not, remove one of your double brackets.  If so, does `new_words = [[word for word in test[0] if word not in removed]]` do what you want?

Comment: In the real data, there are 11 different lists (a corpus made of 11 documents) nested in the Test list. This solution didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: So you can insert the test index in your command: `new_words = [word for word in test[0] if word  not in removed]`  and if the data test contains many lists, you can use another loop or specify the exact numbers.

Comment: Since you didn't show nor describe your "real" data, I'm unsure as to what you want now.  Do you want to remove `anual` from each list within the `test` list?

Comment: @rickhg12hs that is exactly the case. 

The real data are 11 curricula from different organizations. They are organized in a dataframe with two columns, one with the names of the organizations and the other their curricula (about 1000pgs each). The Test list mirrors the 11 nested lists. I am not being able to remove some left over stop words that are messing my analysis.

Comment: Francisco, welcome to Stack Overflow. You didn't have any stupidness, it's just some misunderstanding or lose of information. To further help you, can you please explain more, what I understood is that you have a list, you have a function, which removes certain words if they meet the 'if' criteria , but it doesn't remove the word? If that is yes, try adding in the function print hello world, if it printed, means the if is getting response, and the command in it is not working, if no print was executed, it might be that the criteria doesn't work properly or also both, the if, and the command

Answer (score 1):

I see, maybe the function is not working properly, so you can use the following code just add it and set everything to work properly yourself it would be easy.

```py
words = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
stopwords = ['a', 'c']
for word in list(words):  # iterating on a copy since removing will mess things up
    if word in stopwords:
        words.remove(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

This program works in python compiler.

But in jupyter you have to change the following:

remove one of `[` and `]` from source data:

```
test = ['acesso em',
'agindo',
'alegre',
'ambiente escolar',
'ambientes digitais',
'anual',
'aplicativos digitais',
'apresentar conclusões',
'argumentação cuidado',
'articuladas projeto',
'associadas eixos',
'associação',
'ativas',
'atos linguagem',
'avaliar oportunidades',
'bairro',
'base critérios',
'base estudos',
'bibliográfica exploratória',
'blogs',
'buscando apresentar',
'campo artístico']
removed = ['anual']
new_words = [word for word in test if word  not in removed]
new_words
```

Output:

```
 ['acesso em',
 'agindo',
 'alegre',
 'ambiente escolar',
 'ambientes digitais',
 'aplicativos digitais',
 'apresentar conclusões',
 'argumentação cuidado',
 'articuladas projeto',
 'associadas eixos',
 'associação',
 'ativas',
 'atos linguagem',
 'avaliar oportunidades',
 'bairro',
 'base critérios',
 'base estudos',
 'bibliográfica exploratória',
 'blogs',
 'buscando apresentar',
 'campo artístico']
```

And if you want to access the list elements inside another list, you can enter its index:

```
new_words = [word for word in test[0] if word  not in removed]
```

In this case, there is no need to delete `[]`.

Comment: `python` in a `jupyter` notebook should be the same as any other `python`.  How do you think they are different?

Comment: Because I tested the program in both environments.

Comment: Well, I'm glad my `python` is the same everywhere.  Otherwise, development would be next to impossible.

Comment: For some reason, new_words = [word for word in test[0] if word not in removed] breaks the entire corpus into letters

Comment: From @FranciscoMelloCastro's comments in the original question, you've changed the `test` list in a way that he doesn't want.

Comment: In the last line, I have written a point for this case as well. Please read the answer in full.

Comment: @SaeedEmamYari And if you read all the comments to the original question, you will discover that `test` is a list of 11 lists.  The main code you show is not a nested list, and "In the last line, I have written a point for this case" would only update the first list within `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe seems a bit strange, but if you want to create a new list of lists with some stop words removed, this may work for you.

```py
new_words = [[word for word in mywords if word not in removed] for mywords in test]
```

Try it on [Binder](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/rickhg12hs/Binder/2912fba133e60b5c8d89fda041f067c79a5c8edb?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2FgoodByeStopWords.ipynb).

Comment: Weird that this was downvoted when it's the only answer, so far, that uses the OP's data and provides the desired output ... with a running example.